# Adding foreign attributes to an Entity as if they are its own

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data

For one-to-one relationships, is it possible to put an attribute of a foreign table in an `@Entity` as if it belonged to that `@Entity`? I might explain myself best with an example.

Let's say I have a table `foo` with a big amount of records. Some of these records can have an extra textual property `bar`, but most of them won't. To save space, I'd opt to put that extra property in a separate table `bar`. In my `Foo` POJO, I'd then add a property that looks something like:

```
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "fooID")
private Bar bar;
```

Wherever I'd like to access the `bar` property of my `foo` object, I'd have to write:

```
foo.getBar().getBar();
```

Which looks a bit silly, especially in the case where a `Bar` POJO only has one property `bar`. Could it be possible to use some magical annotations, like Jackson's `@JsonUnwrapped`, that allow me to but `Bar`'s properties directly on `Foo` like so?

```
@OneToOne(...)
@JoinColumn(...)
@MaybeSomeMoreMagicalAnnotations
private String bar;
```

Comment: Not sure I understand.  Java methods allow you to abstract what they return however you want.  method String getBar() {return (bar==null?)null:bar.getBar();}

Comment: Of course but that just moves the problem to my POJO. It's clean on the outside and I like it, but I was wondering if there was an optimal solution to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using the @SecondaryTable annotation on your Foo class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "foo")
@SecondaryTable(name = "bar")
public class Foo {

    @Column(table = "bar")
    private String bar;

    (everything else)
}
```